# What it means by Website or Server not found

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ip, nameserver

I just set up two domain names hosted by 1and1 to point to my VPS. On my VPS, I created a virtual Apache server for each.  I waited a day, and then checked to see if they worked.  Unfortunately, neither work.  What's got me confused is that they both result in different errors.  I have posted the results below for both FF and IE.  Why are they different and what does it mean?  Thanks!

Website 1 with FF

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Website 1 with IE

```
The webpage cannot be found
 HTTP 404
Most likely causes:
•There might be a typing error in the address.
•If you clicked on a link, it may be out of date.
What you can try:
Retype the address.
Go back to the previous page.
Go to  and look for the information you want.
```

Website 2 with FF

```
Server not found
Firefox can't find the server at www.zadaba.com.
Check the address for typing errors such as
ww.example.com instead of
www.example.com
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Website 2 with IE

```
Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
What you can try:
Diagnose Connection Problems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is a webserver configuration issue. The server determined that there was no page to be served based on the requested URI.

The second error is a DNS resolution issue. The browser is unable to resolve the DNS name to an IP address, and the request never hits your VPS at all.